# Looping for files in a directory, but cannot open the files in the directory because it doesn't exist

Tags: python, file, directory

I was trying to read data from a bunch of textfiles in a directory, but getting an error while opening the file

```
import os
fileList = os.listdir("Desktop/SLUI")

for txtName in fileList:
    #Open the textfile
    UIname=str(txtName)
    userDTL=open(UIname,'r')
    if userDTL.mode=='r':
        line=userDTL.readlines()
        string1=line[0]
        string2=line[1]
        string3=line[2]
        UserDTL.close()
    print(string1)
```

Here is the error when I try to run this code via cmd.exe

```
    File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\programName.py", line 24, in <module>
        userDTL=open(UIname,'r')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.txt'
```

Comment: You need to provide full path to the file, not only 'file1.txt'

Comment: It's because `listdir` only return the filenames. So you have to use `os.path.join("Desktop/SLUI", txtName)` to construct the full path inside the `for` loop.

Comment: When you use the Open function, the path used is relative to current directory. You need to concatenate the filename with the full folder path.

Comment: you only getting the filenames not the path you cand add the folder before filenames or I recommend you to use glob

Comment: Thanks! It's working well now <3

Comment: if you use glob to find the files, it will return a list of full paths so you don't need to worry about this error..

Answer (score 0):

It's because `os.listdir` only displays the name of the files, and to open them you need the whole path.
You need to redefine UIname as such:

```
UIname=os.path.join("Desktop/SLUI",txtName) # I don't think you need the string conversion.
```

`os.path.join()` will properly join two (or more) bits of paths, whichever OS you use.

I'm not really familiar with how Python works on Windows, so you might need to replace "Desktop/SLUI" by the appropriate path to your desktop (C:\Users*****\Desktop).